# Eth0 doesn't keep it's settings after reboot

Tags: networking, pi-2

To start, I'll say it's been nearly 2 decades since I've fiddled with *nix, and that was OBSD.. so to say I'm rusty is an understatement... And I'm new to Rpi.

So I've edited the `/etc/network/interfaces` file, and added my desired static IP and netmask, I exit, I pull the interface down and back up, and it is set and working.. I reboot, and I have some weird IP again, the file is as I left it... 
I must be missing something somewhere, what is it?

`/etc/network/interfaces` is 
  GNU nano 2.2.6         File: /etc/network/interfaces

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth- inet manual



allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet manual
    wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf

allow-hotplug wlan1
iface wlan1 inet manual
    wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

`/etc/dhcpcd.conf` is

```
interface eth0 static ip_address= 192.168.1.250/16



hostname


clientid

persistent


option rapid_commit


option domain_name_servers, domain_name, domain_search, host_name
option classless_static_routes

option ntp_servers



require dhcp_server_identifier

slaac private

nohook lookup-hostname
```

OK, I removed all the comments that seemed to be offensive to formatting

Comment: See the tutorial at [How do I set up networking/WiFi/Static IP](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/37921/8697) 
 which explains why it doesn't work and how to fix it

Comment: I tried that now, and it certainly doesn't explain why it doesn't work... I edited `/etc/dhcpcd.conf` instead (reverted interfaces to what it was) and no go.. every time I reboot my IP is `169.254.141.114`

Comment: It does explain, but I guess this requires more understanding of Linux. If you want help paste the current contents of the files you changed into your question i.e. `/etc/network/interfaces` and others. `169.254.141.114` is a link-local address so for some reason it is not getting an IP address.

Comment: `/etc/dhcpcd.conf` starts with the lines 
`interface eth0
static ip_address= 192.168.1.250/16`

Comment: The rest of both files are as issued with the latest Raspbian-Jessie

Comment: GNU nano 2.2.6         File: /etc/network/interfaces

# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)

# Please note that this file is written to be used with dhcpcd
# For static IP, consult /etc/dhcpcd.conf and 'man dhcpcd.conf'

# Include files from /etc/network/interfaces.d:source-directory /etc/network/in$

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth- inet manual

allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet manual
    wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf

allow-hotplug wlan1
iface wlan1 inet manual
    wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf

Comment: wow... formatting here really sucks!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36538/discussion-between-rx7man-and-milliways).

Comment: Are you problem solved? Could you update your question with new details?, can specify which network interface are you trying to connect?

Answer (score 1):

English is not my native language so please be patient.

Maybe is a typo error in your `interfaces` file, change **the `-` for `0`**

```
auto eth0
allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth- inet manual ---> iface eth0 inet manual
```

I would advice to try first with `dhcp`, if you have a screen or you can check the I.P. from your router that the raspberry is leasing, then you can come back to the `interfaces` file and choose `manual` or even `static` set-up.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.1.250
subnet 255.255.0.0
```

Note the `static` instead of `manual`.

Comment: This would work if Raspbian had `networking` enabled by default, which is unfortunately not the case.